# Can this question be reopened: "Are there open source alternatives to Bitbucket, Github, Kiln, and similar DVCS browsing and management tools"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question

I have rewritten my question so as to remove any polling type questions. Can this question be reopened?

[Are there open source alternatives to Bitbucket, Github, Kiln, and similar DVCS browsing and management tools?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/129152/are-there-open-source-alternatives-to-bitbucket-github-kiln-and-similar-dvcs)

Comment: Ryan, since my close vote was on the original version of the question, I'm extremely happy you took the time to revise it, and I've set a bounty to get a bit more attention to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for coming back to edit your question. I think that with the clearly defined criteria you provided, we can give it another go.

Reopened.